# Parse date format to DateTime c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

How to parse this string:

```
 "\"2014-01-02T23:00:00.000Z\"" to DateTime
```

This didn't work:

```
    DateTime? dateTimeFormat= string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString) ?? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(inputString);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify exact format of you datetime to the [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method:

```
string input = "\"2014-01-02T23:00:00.000Z\"";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "'\"'yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fff'Z\"'", null);
```

Description of format provided:

```
'\"'           - match first "
yyyy-MM-dd     - match 2014-01-02
'T'            - match T
HH:mm:ss.fff   - match 23:00:00.000
'Z\"'          - match Z"
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help

```
string test = "2014-01-02T23:00:00.000Z";
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.ParseExact(your_date.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reformat the string to put in the proper format, then parse

```
string =  "\"2014-01-02T23:00:00.000Z\"";
string = substring(3,10) + " " + substring(14,8); //"2014-01-02 23:00:00"
time = DateTime.Parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2014-01-02T23:00:00.000Z" , "yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Maybe this might work.

Add- 
    using System.Globalization;

Answer (score 0):

I've tried almost all of the method/codes in this answer but none of them worked for me. Although, using parts of code of previous answer to this question, I did this and it worked perfectly for me.

```
var d = "2019-01-11T05:00:00.000Z"; //Date

int year = Convert.ToInt32(d.Substring(0, 4));
int month = Convert.ToInt32(d.Substring(5, 2));
int day = Convert.ToInt32(d.Substring(8, 2));

var time = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

I was not concerned with the time. You can add it if you want.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer on a question with several replies, please show the Pros of yours.